# Why is Linux shell script heavy compared to Windows?

Tags: linux, windows

Why are so many of the GNU/Linux utilities implemented as shell scripts when comparatively, almost all of the similar windows utilities are implemented as compiled code existing in binary formats? What are the some of the reasons for this?

Comment: This article <http://www.softpanorama.org/People/Shell_giants/introduction.shtml> describes the early days of UNIX and the benefits Bell Labs gained from the Thompson and Mashey shells . Shell scripting was a more flexible language above C, although heavily used scripts were sometimes later converted to C for performance, after requirements had settled.[...] Raising the language level enabled vast improvements in productivity in that decade, as C replaced assembly language, and script-level languages greatly augmented C. You could argue then that downstream unixes inherited from this momentum

Answer (score 10):

To answer that, young Padawan, you merely have to consult the writings of those who were working on Unix when *Tyrannosaurus Rex* roamed a still-cooling planet.

Deliberate upon the palimpsest so humbly offered by a sage of those halcyon dream-time days, one [Eric Raymond](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond). Verily shall his great pièce-de-résistance, "[The Art of Unix Programming](http://catb.org/esr/writings/taoup/html/)", enlighten the novice.

The chapter of interest of that  marvellous tome is the felicitous number 7: "[The importance of being textual](http://catb.org/esr/writings/taoup/html/ch05s01.html)". Read well, young Grasshopper, and you will learn.

*Inter alia*, the sensei explaineth that "Text streams are a valuable universal format because they're easy for human beings to read, write, and edit without specialized tools. These formats are (or can be designed to be) transparent".

Reflect deeply, as would a Zen master, upon these judicious words, O gentle novice, that thou shalt achieve the nirvana of great insight!

Humbly offered as a response to our fellow-traveller's admirable quest for knowledge along the One True Path that is Unix in this, the year of Our Lord 2016.

Comment: excellent +1, the very reason why UNIX is so simple and yet sophisticated

Comment: Padawan *and* Grasshopper? You've crossed the streams across generations.

Comment: Beyond the narrow confines of time and space, thou shalt find oh acolyte, the quest for knowledge is.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [Interactive features](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_command_shells#Interactive_features) table and [programming features](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_command_shells#Programming_features) table on the page for [command shells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_command_shells) on Wikipedia, and compare e.g. the features of the "simple" old Bourne shell with `command.com`. You'll see that even the Bourne shell has several green boxes that features are available, where `command.com` has none.

With windows `cmd.exe` the situation is somewhat better, but that gave `sh` about 20 years of headstart.

Windows Powershell only recently seemed to have caught up with Unix shells to actually do development.

Comment: Also, if one ships ONLY the binary, one can conceal the source. Microsoft does this.